# Where can I find SQL Server Installation Center?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to install SSIS in SQL Server (not the SSIS in Visual Studio). And the way I see this should be done is with SQL Server installation center. However try as I might, I can not find it. I saw in this (https://youtu.be/reamHZ4hKdU) YouTube video to click on setup, but I can't find that either. Where can I find SQL Server Installation Center?

[sql server installation center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TzXF.png)

Comment: It's the full SQL Server installer. Use whatever version you have installed for the SQL Server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to get to the sql sever installer. My sql server is from 2016 and I can't find the installer.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I didn't think of this. I am on Window Server 2012 R2 and when I did a search for Sql Server Installation Center it came up. Thank you Jacob H for your help.